# How to optimize STDistance execution?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, spatial

I am creating temporary table during stored procedure execution with the following structure:

```
[ID] BIGINT
[Point] GEOGRAPHY
```

the `ID` is not unique - there are about `200` records for each `ID`.

I need to find a list with distinct `IDs` for which there is at least one `Point` to `Point` distance larger then constant value (for example `200` meters).

So, I am using something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DS1.[ID]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[ID] = DS2.[ID]
WHERE DS1.Point.STDistance(DS2.Point) > 200
```

For 23 000 points, the query is executed for `4-5` seconds. As I am expecting to have more values, I need to find better solution.

I guess that if there is faster way, I can always create a materialized table and implement additional logic that will calculated this on `ID` base.

I have created a spatial index, but the query optimizer is not using it. If I use a `hint` like this `WITH (INDEX(SPATIAL_idx_test))` I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8635, Level 16, State 4, Line 78
>   The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a spatial index hint.  Reason: Spatial indexes do not support the comparator supplied in the predicate.  Try removing the index hints or removing `SET FORCEPLAN`.
>   `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of any other improvements you make, be sure to test the impact on spatial execution times of enabling trace flags 6532, 6533, and 6534 (start-up only). These turn on *native code spatial implementations*. SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3 or SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2 required ([Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3107399/spatial-performance-improvements-in-sql-server-2012-and-2014)). Native compilation is [on by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql) from SQL Server 2016.

For `STDistance` the important trace flag is **6533**. In a simple test, this improved execution time **from 2100ms to 150ms** without using a spatial index on my laptop's SQL Server 2012 instance.

Example adapted from [SQL 2016 – It Just Runs Faster: Native Spatial Implementation(s)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobsql/2016/06/03/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-native-spatial-implementations/) by Bob Ward):

#### Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SpatialTest
(
    ID      integer NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Points  geography NOT NULL
);
GO
-- Insert random sample points
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
DECLARE @Point float = 1.1;

INSERT dbo.SpatialTest (Points) 
VALUES ('POINT(' + CAST(@Point AS varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Point AS varchar(20)) + ')' );

WHILE(SCOPE_IDENTITY() < 100000)
BEGIN
    SET @Point = @Point + RAND(SCOPE_IDENTITY());
    IF (@Point > 90.0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Point = -89.0 + RAND(SCOPE_IDENTITY());
    END;

    INSERT dbo.SpatialTest (Points) 
    VALUES ( 'POINT(' + CAST(@Point AS varchar(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Point AS varchar(20)) + ')' );
END;
```

#### Test Query

```
DBCC TRACEON (6533);
DBCC TRACESTATUS;
GO
DECLARE 
    @s datetime2 = SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    @g geography = 'POINT(1.0 80.5)';

SELECT [Matches] = COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM dbo.SpatialTest AS ST
WHERE ST.Points.STDistance(@g) > 10000000.5
OPTION (MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE);

SELECT [Elapsed STDistance Query (ms)] = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @s, SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

Average execution times: 2100ms (trace flag off); 150ms (trace flag on).

Answer (score 3):

> For 23 000 points, the query is executed for 4-5 seconds. As I am expecting to have more values, I need to find better solution. [...] I have created a spatial index, but the query optimizer is not using it. If I use a hint like this `WITH (INDEX(SPATIAL_idx_test))` I am getting the following error

The only answer here makes no mentioning of an index. I just wanted to say if you migrate to [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), the spatial extension for PostgreSQL which is practically the reference implementation for GIS and far more full featured, you'll have [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). This **will** make use of a spatial index.

```
CREATE INDEX ON datasource USING gist( point );

SELECT DISTINCT ds1.id
FROM datasource AS ds1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM datasource ds2
  WHERE ds1.id = ds2.id
  AND NOT ST_DWithin( ds1.point, ds2.point, 200)
);
```

That will use the index to resolve `ST_DWithin`, and then invert that set. You may be able to do even better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ds1.id
FROM datasource AS ds1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM datasource AS ds2
  WHERE ds1.id = ds2=id
  ORDER BY ds1.point <=> ds.point DESC
  LIMIT 1;
) AS t2
WHERE ds1.id = t2.id
AND NOT ST_DWithin( ds1.point, t2.point, 200);
```

That will only run the distance compare once, and it'll use KNN to sort on index.

You can even reduce it to one index lookup with [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html).

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE INDEX ON datasource USING gist( id, point );
```

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) and [PostGIS](http://wwwpostgis.net/) are free and open source software.

I answered a question like this [back in Janurary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/266741/6052), but I think the buffer with tolerance is probably better. If you need more accuracy though use `.buffer()`

Answer (score 3):

The query in the question wants to find pairs of points that are **more** than 200 meters apart.
Such kind of query is not supported by the spatial indexes in SQL Server.

Microsoft docs [Spatial Indexes Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview) say:

> **Geography Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes**
>
> Under certain conditions, spatial indexes support the following
>   set-oriented geography methods: `STIntersects()`, `STEquals()` and
>   `STDistance()`. To be supported by a spatial index, these methods must
>   be used within the `WHERE` clause of a query, and they must occur
>   within a predicate of the following general form:
>
> ```
> geography1.method_name(geography2) comparison_operator valid_number
> ```
>
> To return a non-null result, `geography1` and `geography2` must have
>   the same Spatial Reference Identifier (SRID). Otherwise, the method
>   returns `NULL`.
>
> Spatial indexes support the following predicate forms:
>
> ```
> geography1.STIntersects(geography2) = 1
>
> geography1.STEquals(geography2) = 1
>
> geography1.STDistance(geography2) < number
>
> geography1.STDistance(geography2) <= number
> ```

As you can see, the query in the question doesn't have one of the supported forms.

That's why you are getting this error message "Reason: Spatial indexes do not support the comparator supplied in the predicate" when you are trying to force use of the index.

You may try to rewrite the query to make a Cartesian product with all combinations of points and "subtract" from it a set of points that are within 200 meters, but I doubt that it would be more efficient, even if it used the index.

---

I have a table with ~3000 rows with geography locations in my database and I tried the simplified version of the query from the question on it. Adding `AND DS1.Point.STDistance(DS2.Point) IS NOT NULL` was not necessary, the index was used without this clause.

Index was used only when comparison was `< 200`.

It was not used when comparison was `> 200`.

```
SELECT
    DS1.[Building ID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblPhysicalBuildings] AS DS1
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[tblPhysicalBuildings] AS DS2
WHERE 
    DS1.LocationPoint.STDistance(DS2.LocationPoint) < 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
;
```

[image: less]

```
SELECT
    DS1.[Building ID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblPhysicalBuildings] AS DS1
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[tblPhysicalBuildings] AS DS2
WHERE 
    DS1.LocationPoint.STDistance(DS2.LocationPoint) > 200
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
;
```

[image: more]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that may be faster is to use the [STIntersects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933962(v=sql.110).aspx) and [BufferWithTolerance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933987(v=sql.110).aspx) methods to check if one point is within a certain distance of another.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DS1.[ID]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[ID] = DS2.[ID]
WHERE DS2.STIntersects(DS1.BufferWithTolerance(200, 0.9, 0)) = 1
```

Do note though that BufferWithTolerance has a tolerance value (in my example 0.9) that is essentially a trade-off value between speed and accuracy.  If you want exact results this probably isn't the method for you.  I also seem to recall that STIntersects is an imprecise method but I can't find any reference to back that up at the moment so maybe I am mistaken about that.